# How to remove everything from child in firebase without specific child in it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove everything from child "UserRequests" in the database, but leave it's specific child "DoNotRemove":

```
databaseReference.child("UserRequests").removeValue();
```

I really need to do this or the other options will be to get only one child from "UserRequests" that isn't "DoNotRemove", do what I have to with it and then delete it OR get only one child from "UserRequests" having child "Nickname" (because "DoNotRemove" has no child), do what I have to do with it and then delete it.

http://oi65.tinypic.com/15xspxe.jpg

Bassically I have to remove everything from "UserRequests" except child "DoNotRemove" OR get ONLY one child from "UserRequests" but not "DoNotRemove".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserRequests");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("Nickname").startAt(" "); // space it the first printable character

query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
    }
    ...
```

So this will get every child node under `UserRequests` that has a property `Nickname`. Since a space is the first printable character, this returns each node with such a property. It skips your `DoNotRemove` node, which doesn't have a `Nickname` property.

Comment: I get it, this is perfect! Thank you